# Java class. org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, google-cloud-dataflow

I am pulling data from Oracle using dataflow job in java. While running my dataflow job with a Direct runner, I am facing below error

jsonPayload: {
  exception:  "java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory$1.typedApply(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:192)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory$1.typedApply(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:163)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.graph.Networks$TypeSafeNodeFunction.apply(Networks.java:63)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.graph.Networks$TypeSafeNodeFunction.apply(Networks.java:50)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.graph.Networks.replaceDirectedNetworkNodes(Networks.java:87)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.create(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:123)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.doWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:334)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:288)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:134)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:114)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:101)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:36)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeSetup(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DoFnInstanceManagers$ConcurrentQueueInstanceManager.deserializeCopy(DoFnInstanceManagers.java:63)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DoFnInstanceManagers$ConcurrentQueueInstanceManager.peek(DoFnInstanceManagers.java:45)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.UserParDoFnFactory.create(UserParDoFnFactory.java:94)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DefaultParDoFnFactory.create(DefaultParDoFnFactory.java:74)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.createParDoOperation(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:262)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.access$000(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:84)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory$1.typedApply(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:181)
    ... 14 more

And for more clearance. please refer my code below,
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create();
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
    pipeline.apply(JdbcIO.>read().withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//:1521/orcl").withUsername("user_name").withPassword("pass_word")).withQuery("select SUPPLIER_ID,SUPPLIER_NAME from suppliers").withRowMapper(new JdbcIO.RowMapper>() {
                        @Override
                        public KV mapRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
                            System.out.println("=====================inside resultset====================");
                            KV kv = KV.of(resultSet.getString("label"), resultSet.getString("name"));
                            return kv;
                        }
                    }).withCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), StringUtf8Coder.of()))).apply(GroupByKey.create())

Also I having Oracle version 11g so I am using ojdbc6.jar here

Please help me

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace; the real reason is further down in the stacktrace (although connecion reset indicates it is a problem with the network connection).

Comment: Hey..  please check detail error

Comment: That isn't the full exception stacktrace (or otherwise Beam is throwing away parts of the stacktrace)

Comment: This is detail stack driver log which I see

Comment: Were you able to figure out the issue?
Getting the same error and I am wondering if this is a network configuration issue